# List of strings is not rendered to JSON

Tags: json, grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class

```
class UserProfile {

    List<String> interests = [];
    ObjectId id;
    String username;
    String password;
    String email;

    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

which is properly persisted in mongodb by gorm

```
def user = new UserProfile(username:"name",password:"pass",email:"asd@asd.com",interests: ['women','dogfight']);
user.save()
```

which could be verified in mongo console:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("528fd78003646357efb421c0"), "email" : "asd@asd.com", "interests" : [  "women",  "dogfight"], "password" : "pass", "username" : "name", "version" : 0 }

so i get this object by 
`UserProfile.find() as JSON` in controller and got

{"class":"domain.users.UserProfile","id":{"class":"org.bson.types.ObjectId","inc":-273407552,"machine":56910679,"new":false,"time":1385158528000,"timeSecond":1385158528},"email":"asd\u0040asd.com","password":"pass","username":"name"}

as you can see list of interests unfortunately was not rendered

I would appreciate any help. Thanx.

P.S. Grails v2.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying association in domain class should help.

```
static hasMany = [interests: String]
```

Answer (score 2):

Collection inside domain class is unnatural to GORM. When using SQL database, you'll be in trouble to persist such an entity. So I believe, the converters in Grails are ignoring these attributes.

Than you need to write your own marshaller, to make the conversion. There are many answers about Grails marshallers here at SO, or here is a nice blog post:

http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/16/custom-json-marshalling-in-grails-done-right/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
…
JSON.use('deep')
render someObject as JSON
```

Reference can be found at http://grails.org/Converters+Reference